# Resolve missing references using Nuget failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bundle, nuget

I checked out a project form Team Foundation. As you can see in the picture, I used nuget to restore the missing packages. However, the reference problems are not resolved at all.

[image: My current project]

When I right click on my solution and choose Manage Nuget Packet for Solution, here is what I've got

[image: My current project]

I thought it means that I have download all the package but they are not added to my project because there are still many build errors. If I use Package Manager Console to download each package separately, the version will conflict with the original. I would like to see if there are any automatic way to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to check out the package folder outside the project folder.